# Pip no instala paquetes: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, pip, pygame

Quiero instalar paquetes para Python 3.6.5
Al ingresar pip install pygame me aparece esto:

```
C:\Users\rayvi>pip install shell
Collecting shell
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/19/5fc161e830b08bf2b419a04b0105f2dbf095759148d38cd1e99feadc4146/shell-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: shell
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\program files 
(x86)\\microsoft visual studio\\shared\\python36_64\\Lib\\site- 
packages\\shell.py'
```

Comment: **Permission denied**: tu usuario no tiene permisos de escritura en el directorio donde quieres instalar, de hecho no se tienen permisos de escritura por defecto en todo Program Files . Abrir la terminal donde lanzas pip  como **administrador**  debería solucionar el problema. No uso VS pero para instalar paquetes deberías mirarte https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545749/7131499.

Comment: Te recomiendo buscar información sobre los entornos virtuales en python, Esto te evitará posibles conflicto de dependencias cuando estes trabajando en distintos proyectos y que utilicen algunas librerias que tengan incompatibilidad entre ellas mismas.

Answer (score 2):

## Solución 1

En Windows te conviene ejecutar pip usando el ejecutable python que debería tener acceso a la carpeta donde está instalado pip.

```
python -m pip install shell
```

Para poder hacer esto, python tiene que estar configurado en tu PATH.

## Solución 2

Dar más permisos de acceso a la carpeta. Para esto, en el *Administrador de Archivos*, andá a la carpeta donde está instalado Python; hacé click con el botón derecho, seleccioná *Propiedades*; en la pestaña *Seguridad* hacé click en *Editar*; buscá en *Nombre de grupos o usuarios*, el ítem *Usuarios* y marcá *Modificar* y *Escritura*; dale *Aceptar* a los dos recuadros. Ahora tu usuario debería poder usar sin problemas pip.

## Solución 3

En caso de que no sea así también podés usar el Símbolo de Sistema como *Administrador*. Para esto buscá *Símbolo de Sistema* en el *Menú Inicio* y hacé click con el botón derechó y dale en *Ejecutar como administrador*

**Esta solución no es recomendable porque cada cosa que instales con permisos de *Administrador* luego vas a necesitar los mismos permisos para usarla.**

---

Agregadas soluciones 2 y 3

Answer (score 0):

Ubiquese en la raiz de donde se encuenta pip "C:\Python27\Scripts", Tenga encuenta que si otro software ya habia usado pyton preferiblemente se encuente en esat carpta. desde la consola cmd, iniciandola con provilegios de superadministrador "Ejecutar como administrador" y dirijiendose hasta la ruta cd .. para regeresar y cd nombre de carpeta para direcinarse hasta pip y ejecutando nuemanete lo instalara.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que tengas un problema de conectividad del MIRROR PyPi
proba con esto
pip install -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple [nombre del paquete]

Por Ejemplo
pip install -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple flask

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/400259)